# Left Align Description List Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some data to display like:

[image]

I want to left-align all the values to the edge of the longest label. I can think of at least four options:

1. [`<table>`](https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/poyrbgy)
2. [fixed width labels](https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/PoNKzwL)
3. [splitting labels and values across bootstrap columns](https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/poyrboj)
4. [the way bootstrap suggests to do it](https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/PoNKNgX) (suggestion from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#description-list-alignment)).

I don't like the `<table>` option because this doesn't feel like tabular data - there are no headers or anything.
I don't like the fixed width label idea because it seems brittle to changes in content and/or translations of the labels.
I don't like splitting the labels and values across columns because it semantically separates the `<dt>`s from the `<dd>`s which I *assume* is bad for accessibility (let me know if this is incorrect!).
I like the way bootstrap suggests handling it but our designer doesn't want the values getting farther from the labels as the page gets wider.

Is there a more idiomatic way to handle this or is one of these options fine?

Comment: Can we use js and get the width of long one and apply it to other labels ?

Comment: You can use css `grid` here. Set label width to `auto` and it will take the longest width automatically.

Comment: @AbbasEbadian I believe we could use JS but I was hoping for a pure-CSS solution. Will default to that if no idiomatic CSS solution surfaces!

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Very cool! I hadn't heard of `grid`. I played around with it a little and came up with this - https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/mdPMrGR. Is that about right?

Comment: Yup there you go! You can also add `grid-column-gap` property to add some space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670967/left-align-description-list-content?noredirect=1#comment112592673_63670967) there is a css `grid` solution:

```html
<dl class="grid">
  <dt>A Label:</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  <dt>A Longer Label:</dt>
  <dd>Value 2</dd>
  <dt>Short:</dt>
  <dd>Value 3</dd>
</dl>
```

```css
.grid {
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

dt {
  grid-column: 1;
}
dd {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

that can be viewed in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/mdPMrGR).

Comment: One may want to consider adding `dt { grid-column: 1 }` and `dd { grid-column: 2}`, to make sure the elements are positioned in the correct columns. It becomes relevant, if you have multiple `dd` to one `dt` (which is allowed).

Comment: @RoToRa Sorry - I'm confused by this. This looks like a good idea and makes sense but when I update my codepen with that and I add a second `dd` it still ends up in the first column - https://codepen.io/mlodato517/pen/wvGqoEN. Did I do that wrong? Or am I reading your comment incorrectly?

Comment: You've got the syntax wrong. You can't nest rules like that in plain CSS. You need to either move the `dt` and `dt` rules outside the `.grid` rule, or use a preprocessor such as SCSS by clicking on the cog icon beside the "CSS" headline and choosing a preprocessor.

Comment: @RoToRa hahah sorry :facepalm:. The actual code I'm working with is scss and I forgot to switch back in the codepen. updated it and it looks great! Thanks. I'll update the answer too